# How to get a certain value of a certain key in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, attributeerror

```
G={(-1, 1): [(0, 1)],
 (0, 0): [(1, 0), (0, 1)],
 (0, 1): [(1, 1), (0, 2), (-1, 1), (0, 0)],
 (0, 2): [(0, 1)],
 (1, 0): [(2, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0)],
 (1, 1): [(0, 1), (1, 0)],
 (2, 0): [(1, 0)]}
```

I have this dictionary in python and i want to go through each value of a certain key.
For example i have the key: (0,0)
I want to print each value seperately like this:

Output:

```
value 0 : (1,0)
value 1 : (0,1)
```

and I have this code

```
key=(0,0)
for v in range (len(G[key])):
    print ("value ", v, ":", G[(0,0)].get(v))
```

**G[(0,0)].get(v)** is wrong and i get a message:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Do you know what should i use instead?

Comment: You could do `G[(0,0)][v]`. Although in Python you can iterate *directly* over the elements of a list, so you could do `for v in G[key]: `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

enumerate will get you the index and value:

```
key=(0,0)
for idx,v in enumerate(G[key]):
    print ("value ", idx, ":", v)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `print` build-in function with param `sep='\n'`:

```
print(*G[(0,0)], sep='\n')
```

output:

```
(1, 0)
(0, 1)
```

or you can use:

```
print(*['value %s : %s' % t for t in enumerate(G[(0,0)])], sep='\n')
```

output:

```
value 0 : (1, 0)
value 1 : (0, 1)
```